# Polymer Chrome 36 and Packaged Apps

Tags: google-chrome-app, polymer

If I want to target only Chrome 36 + / Packaged apps with Chrome 36, is there a build that does not include the platform polyfills with best performance?

Second question, If I am looking for a single page application reference implementation, is there any best practice guidance? I went through this one so far

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/01/Yo-Polymer-A-Whirlwind-Tour-Of-Web-Component-Tooling

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Niranjan

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Polymer requires platform.js to function. The team is [working](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/polymer-dev/1maKkAApBS0/M-4oBnpaDq0J) on providing a way to use Polymer without loading the polyfills that are implemented natively.

The Polymer team is also [working](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/polymer-dev/fAvqDo40tMk/m85JtEeuP_MJ) on documenting good Polymer Single Page Application practices. For now, Eric Bidelman has a simple [demo](http://polymer-change.appspot.com/demos/spa.html) (with [source](https://github.com/ebidel/polymer-change/tree/master/demos)) available.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Glad to hear the team is working on both the items.

Here are couple of my thoughts, If polymer takes the approach of "Chrome packaged app / Chrome 36+" first approach, the platform can have lot more production wins. It might also lead to more performing implementation. Polymer can support other browsers with progressive enhancement approach.It can also help people with hybrid applications (https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps). Thanks